# goalPrefix is not used over default plugin prefix in a maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, overriding, pom.xml

While using Maven, I want to use tomcat7 instead of old version(e.g., tomcat5) via `mvn tomcat:run`(note I use `tomcat:run` not `tomcat7:run`) . To do so, according to [maven official reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html),  I set my pom.xml as:

```
...
<build>
   ...
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <configuration>
          <goalPrefix>tomcat</goalPrefix>
      </configuration>
      ...
```

However it turned out that the `mvn tomcat:run` still use tomcat-maven-plugin but not tomcat7-maven-plugin. Looks like maven didn't honor the `goalPrefix`. Why ? How can I let maven know the `tomcat:run` should use the tomcat7-maven-plugin ?

Comment: You need to use `mvn tomcat7:run` cause you start a goal instead of a life-cycle. Apart from that the tomcat7 plugin does not has a paremeter `goalPrefix` in its configuration so where did you get that information from?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I got the `goalPrefix` from the [official maven reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html).

Comment: You haven't read the docs very well, cause it's only valid if you developing a plugin yourself and not using it.